# Will Matlab respond exceptions raised from VS compiled DLL?

Tags: matlab, exception, dll

Here's a brief summary for what happened: basically, I'm trying to rewrite a MATLAB program to a C# program, where both of them utilized function implemented in a VS compiled library.

For Matlab:

```
val = MyDLL.MyFunc(int32(a),int32(b),int32(c),int32(d));
```

Where:

```
MyDLL= actxserver('MyLib.MyClass');
```

As in C#, it's directly calling the function:

```
obj = new MyLib.MyClass;
val = obj.MyFunc(int32(a),int32(b),int32(c),int32(d));
```

However, in C# program, an exception from MyFunc would be raised but in MATLAB program nothing happens. Since they are essentially calling the same function from the same library, I reckon whether it could be the reason that MATLAB doesn't actually respond to exception raised from outer library?

Any advice would be helpful, thanks!

P.S.: All arguments match with each other and both programs are absolutely calling the very same function.

Comment: Because MATLAB is not standard I/O, so you can not raise standard I/O exceptions. There are ways to do so, with the mex library, but you'd need to replace the exceptions in your C# to mex ones.

Comment: Thanks Ander, in that case, how would MATLAB treat this line of code then? Would it just ignore it and proceed? For example, in my sample code, will val just be assigned as 0? I asked this because I want to make sure whether this exception actually happens both in MATLAB and C#, or it's just ignored by MATLAB.

Comment: The exception should happen I think, as it will trigger the termination of the code. MATLAB will detect that whatever it called, its over, and continue.